# WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val-loss available, skipping

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
epochs = 100
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=15,
        fill_mode ="nearest",
        horizontal_flip = True,
        zoom_range = 0.2)


checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = "CDX_Best.h5", monitor='val-accuracy', save_best_only = True, verbose=1)
start = time.time()
 
history=Model.fit_generator(train_datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size = bs),
                            steps_per_epoch = len(X_train)//bs,
                            validation_data = (X_valid, y_valid),
                            validation_steps = len(X_valid)//bs,
                            epochs =epochs,
                            callbacks= [checkpointer]
                            )
 
end = time.time()
duration = end - start
print ('\n This Model took %0.2f seconds (%0.1f minutes) to train for %d epochs'%(duration, duration/60, epochs) )
```

Epoch 1/100
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:22: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
522/522 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1936 - accuracy: 0.9213WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val-accuracy available, skipping.
522/522 [==============================] - 49s 93ms/step - loss: 0.1936 - accuracy: 0.9213
Epoch 2/100
522/522 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1863 - accuracy: 0.9273WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val-accuracy available, skipping.
522/522 [==============================] - 48s 93ms/step - loss: 0.1863 - accuracy: 0.9273
Epoch 3/100
522/522 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1770 - accuracy: 0.9326WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val-accuracy available, skipping.
522/522 [==============================] - 48s 92ms/step - loss: 0.1770 - accuracy: 0.9326
Epoch 4/100
522/522 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1832 - accuracy: 0.9271WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val-accuracy available, skipping.
522/522 [==============================] - 48s 92ms/step - loss: 0.1832 - accuracy: 0.9271

Comment: the model is not able to read `validation_data = (X_valid, y_valid)`, as from the outputs, valid  accuracy numbers are missing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

simply see the monitor value monitor='val_accuracy' and matrixes return from the working process required validation process events.

Sample: << Custom return your handwritting benchmasks >>

```
import tensorflow as tf

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: CheckPoints
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
checkpointer = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath = "F:\\temp\\CDX_Best.h5", monitor='val_accuracy', save_best_only = True, verbose=1)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Definition
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyLSTMLayer( tf.keras.layers.LSTM ):
    def __init__(self, units, return_sequences, return_state):
        super(MyLSTMLayer, self).__init__( units, return_sequences=True, return_state=False )
        self.num_units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_units])

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
start = 3
limit = 12
delta = 3
sample = tf.range( start, limit, delta )
sample = tf.cast( sample, dtype=tf.float32 )
sample = tf.constant( sample, shape=( 1, 1, 3 ) )
layer = MyLSTMLayer( 3, True, False )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(shape=(1, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape( (1, 3) ),
    layer,
])

model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant( sample, shape=( 1, 1, 1, 3 ) ), tf.constant([0], shape=(1, 1, 1, 1))))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, validation_data=dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=50, callbacks= [checkpointer] )

print( sample )
print( model.predict(sample) )
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 1, 3)              0

 my_lstm_layer (MyLSTMLayer)  (None, 1, 3)             9

=================================================================
Total params: 9
Trainable params: 9
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 1: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.00000, saving model to F:\temp\CDX_Best.h5
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 41ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 16/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 16: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 17/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 17: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 18/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 18: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 19/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 19: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 20/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 20: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 21/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 21: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 22/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 22: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 23/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 23: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 24/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 24: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 25/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 25: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 26/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 26: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 27/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 27: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 28/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 28: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 29/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 29: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 30/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 30: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 31/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 31: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 32/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 32: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 33/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 33: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 34/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 34: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 35/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 35: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 36/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 36: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 37/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 37: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 38/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 38: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 39/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 39: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 40/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 40: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 41/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 41: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 42/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 42: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 43/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 43: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 44/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 44: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 45/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 45: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 46/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 46: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 47/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 47: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 48/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 48: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 49/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 49: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 50/50
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 50: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 1.0986 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
tf.Tensor([[[3. 6. 9.]]], shape=(1, 1, 3), dtype=float32)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 66ms/step
[[[-9.499538  -2.0636537 -6.0241747]]]
```